# How to execute two commands sequentially

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnUnHide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUnHide.Click
    Dim path As String
    fdbUnHide.ShowDialog()
    path = fdbUnHide.SelectedPath
    RunCommandCom(path)
End Sub



Shared Sub RunCommandCom(path As String)
    Dim unhide As String = "attrib -r -s -h /s /d"
    Try
        Shell("cmd.exe /C cd " & path)
        Shell("cmd.exe /C" & unhide)         
End Sub
```

I also tried using "&" but didn't work

```
     Shell("cmd.exe /C cd " & path "& " & unhide)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE:** This answer addresses the problem asked in the question, but it is certainly not the best way of un-hiding a folder and its files.
>
> **THE BEST** and recommended approach is described in [Ctznkane525's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435158).

The problem with your current code is that you are missing a space before the ampersand (`&`).

This:

```
"cmd.exe /C cd " & path & "& " & unhide
```

essentially becomes:

```
"cmd.exe /C cd C:\your\path& attrib -r -s -h /s /d"
```

...making `&` part of the path. You need to add a space before it:

```
"cmd.exe /C cd " & path & " & " & unhide
```

Though be aware that `Shell()` is an outdated function from the VB6 era and shouldn't be used. When "executing commads" (or more correctly: *starting processes*) you should use the [**`Process.Start()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C cd " & path & " & " & unhide)
```

Comment: My GOD! Finally! thank you so much. it worked perfectly.

Comment: @LulGate : Glad I could help. Though you should still try Ctznkane525's edit as executing another process for this is an extremely unnecessary bottleneck. If the files you are trying to unhide are system files then you only need to add another line to his/her loop: `t.Attributes = t.Attributes And Not FileAttributes.System`

Comment: @Visual Vincent Finally an answer that explains the OP issue, great answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you unhide a folder in .net and the files

```
Dim t As New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
t.Attributes = t.Attributes And Not FileAttributes.Hidden

For Each fn As String in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 

    t = New System.IO.FileInfo(fn)
    t.Attributes = t.Attributes And Not FileAttributes.Hidden

Next
```

The attributes are a bitwise flag.   You'll want to import system.io at the top.

Comment: Ok, what about executing other commands sequentially, is it the same way?

Comment: Your change directory command isn't needed...shell isn't the way to run executables ...but this is how you do your specific task.

Comment: BTW the command above didn't work. i adjusted  the code to yours and run it but after selecting a path, the command didn't unhide the files in that directory.

Comment: Did u select a file name or folder name...your initial code implies a folder since it uses CD command

Comment: i selected a path where there are hidden files but nothing unhides in that directory

Comment: Ok...are the Files hidden...or the directory...that's two different things...can provide more code

Comment: files are hidden. but i want a code that unhides both files and folder in a selected path (folder). do you get me?

Comment: `I want a code that unhides both files and folder in a selected path (folder)`, we help with specific problems asking us to do your work is off topic here. You asked about executing 2 different commands right, that is different than your request here in the comments. Edit your question to clearly state your issue and what you need help with. Also @Ctznkane525, how does this answer address the current question?

Comment: the code i wrote above intention is to unhide both files and folders but in order to do that i need a way to execute two commands one after the other in VB. @Codexer

Comment: Understand your request, what happens when you type that question in Google, how many hits come up? From my search, in the first few pages that are shown, show exactly what you want to do.

Comment: i honestly searched before coming here. i didn't find any code that worked.

Comment: @codeexer...the text of the question revealed the user wants to unhide files and folders...my code achieves that...if you are trying to execute shell consecutively to call windows commands...you are probably doing something wrong...there are libraries to do these commands like my example...that's what should be used

Comment: @LulGate : _"files are hidden. but i want a code that unhides both files and folder in a selected path (folder)"_ - Ctzn already edited his/her answer to include that.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 : To match the OP's initial code you should add so that your code clears the `System` and `ReadOnly` attributes as well. Also don't forget to iterate subdirectories. :)